# Searching for an element in log(n) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I came across the following question:

> Suppose I modify a given sorted list of 4n distinct numbers as follows:
>
> Keep elements in even positions (positions 2, 4, 6, ... 4n) as they are. Form n disjoint pairs (i,j) on the odd numbered positions where i = 2k+1 for some k = 0 to n−1 and j = 2k+1 for some k = n to 2n−1.
>
> Now swap elements in positions i and j for every such pair. (i.e. every element in an odd numbered position in the ﬁrst half of the array is swapped with some element in an odd numbered position in the second half of the array. No element is involved in more than one swap (i.e. the swaps are disjoint). You don’t know these (i,j) pairs except that an element in an odd numbered position in the ﬁrst half of the array is swapped with some element in an odd numbered position in the second half. Now given an element x, explain how you can determine whether or not x is in the (new reshuﬄed) array in O(logn) time.

Honestly, I am not sure about how to approach this one. Given x, I can search whether it exists at any even numbered position using binary search. But the numbers in the odd positions are no longer sorted.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well I'm stumped.  I think we need to somehow make use of the fact that if x is not in an even position, then it's between 2 even-position numbers a and b, and there is exactly 1 odd-positioned element (somewhere in the opposite half) y such that a < y < b.  So if we can find some a < y != x < b among the odd positions of the opposite half, then we know x doesn't exist.  But how to do this in O(log n) time?  This y could be in any of n positions!

Comment: As far as I can understand the description you can't. You can test with binary search if `x` is on any even position. If not, you can compare to the `2n`th position to find out if `x` falls in the upper or the lower part of the original array, which implies it could be on an odd position in the lower or upper half of the shuffled array, respectively. But you can't find it except with scanning all `n` odd positions of the respective half of the array. That makes O(n) compexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can determine whether some element `x` is in the new (shuffled) set by doing two binary searches.  The key here is that the odd elements essentially act as "keys" for each other, since they have been swapped in disjoint pairs.

1. Use a standard binary search to look for `x`, making sure that you always choose *even* indices for comparison.  (Using the even indices is crucial, because those are the elements that are still in order.)
2. If `x` is in the array at an even index, it will be found.  If not, we will eventually find two elements `m` and `n` such that `m < x < n` and `index(n) - index(m) == 2`. This means if the array was still sorted, `x` would have to be the element between `m` and `n` (if it was in the array).
3. Consider the element at the index between `m` and `n` - call this `y`.  If element `x` was in the original array, it must have been swapped with `y` when creating the shuffled array.
4. Perform a second binary search to look for `y`, again ensuring you only choose *even* indices for comparison.  Similarly to step 2, you will eventually find two elements `m'` and `n'` such that `m' < y < n'` and `index(n') - index(m') == 2`.  If the array was still sorted, element `y` would be the element between `m'` and `n'`.
5. The element between `m'` and `n'` must be whichever element was swapped with `y`, and therefore whatever element was originally between `m` and `n`.  If this value is not `x`, then `x` does not exist in the array.

Comment: Brilliant!  This would also work even if the odd-positioned elements were grouped into *arbitrary* pairs and then swapped, correct?  (I.e. the requirement that one element in each swapped pair comes from the bottom half and one element from the top half is actually a red herring.)

Comment: Which suggests that there's actually a lot of flexibility in encoding a set of items if all you need is an O(log n) membership test...  Do you know of any data structures that make use of the freedom in ordering odd-positioned items, perhaps to encode some additional information?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, I think that's correct. The bottom/top half swap constraint could be used to refine the algorithm slightly - for instance, when we start the second binary search we already know which half of the array we're looking in - but it's not enough to make much of a difference.